# Selenium/TestNG: correct base test class design

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am developing a Hybrid Framework with Selenium using POM design pattern. In my application there are 8-10 modules say 'User Management' it having 6 options/links/pages. This way all modules having number of pages/links. I have created all the pages under `pageObject` package and all testcases related to each page under different packages. Now I want to run all the testcases through `testNg.xml` file. I am confused with creation of TestBase class which I will be extend with all testcases. I have created `BaseClassTest` as follows:

```java
    public class BaseClassTest {

        ReadConfig readconfig = new ReadConfig();

        public String baseURL = readconfig.getApplicationURL();
        public String username =readconfig.getUsername();
        public String password = readconfig.getPassword();
        public String implicitwait = readconfig.getImplicitWait();
        public String explicitwait = readconfig.getExplicitWait();
        public String pageloadtime = readconfig.getPageLoadTimeOut();

        public static WebDriver driver;
        private Logger log = LoggerHelper.getLogger(BaseClassTest.class);

        public static Logger Logger;

        @Parameters("browser")
        @BeforeClass
        public void setUp(String br)
        {
            if(br.equals("chrome")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",readconfig.getChromePath());
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            else if (br.contentEquals("firefox"))
            {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",readconfig.getFirefoxPath());
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
            else if(br.contentEquals("ie"))
            {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",readconfig.getIEPath());
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            }
            log.info("Initialize WebBrowser");
            driver.get(baseURL);

            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }

        @AfterClass
        public void tearDown() {                        
            driver.quit();
        } 

        public void login()
        {
            LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(driver);
            lp.enterEmailAddress(username);
            lp.enterPassword(password);
            lp.clickOnLoginButton();
        }
```

Here my `testNg.xml` file:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

    <suite name="ABCD" parallel="false">
        <listeners>
            <listener class-name="com.ABCD.extentReport.TestListener"/>
        </listeners>

      <test name="Test">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
         <classes>
          <class name="com.analytics.testCases.UM_TC01_EditUserTest"/>
     <class name="com.analytics.testCases.UM_TC02_ABoutTest"/>

            </classes>
      </test> <!-- Test -->/>
     </suite> <!--  Suite -
```

When I run each executing successfully but it getting login every time as I am calling login test in all Testcases. Should it run that way or on single click (login once) and run all test cases one after another. In that case I can not use

```java
@Parameters("browser")
@BeforeClass
```

so I need to change my base class code. Please guide me how should I design? On a single click should I run each module? Please give suggestion/ reply to my question will be a great help to me.

Comment: Would it work to call `login` once, in the `@BeforeClass` method? Then, once you are logged in, all the tests can execute on the system, and you wouldn't need to login every time. Does doing it that way make sense?

Comment: Tried  login once in the @BeforeClass but does not get login for second class/test  an error is org.openqa.selenium.JsonException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. And it has also skipped the second test of first class/test file.Because their i written atBeforeMethod 
 public void loginintoApp()
 {
  ps = new  CM_PatientSearchPage(driver); 
  login();
  
 } So before executing the second test of same class file it getting an instruction to login again as mentioned in file atBeforeMethod.

Comment: Also tried by removing login method from testcase as already defined in base class but it does not got logged in even. In one testcase file written 2 test and in other class written only one test. All 3 test cases got failed.

Comment: It's still hard to understand what exactly what you're trying to ask. It's currently really hard for anyone wanting to help to even piece the question together. Please have another careful look at  [**how to create a minimum, reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question to follow those guidelines. Try to phrase your question in a much narrower way, I'm sure you'll have better luck getting an answer.

Comment: Okay, I will try my best to phrase my question in much more narrower and understandable way and post it. Thanks.